# How do you flatten nested vectors in Clojure?

Tags: vector, clojure, flatten

I have an atom called history:

```
(def history (atom []))
```

I want it to hold a vector of vectors. each vector is a "command" and the history vector holds the history of all of the commands in order:

```
(swap! history conj current-command)
```

I want it to look like:

```
[["move" 20] ["turn" 90]]
```

but currently it is in the form:

```
atom[[["move" 20] ["turn" 90] ["turn" 120]]]
```

Can I have some tips as how to flatten that to be `[["move" 20] ["turn" 90]]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the initial value of the history atom was not appropriate

```
(def history (atom []))
(swap!  history conj ["move" 20])
(swap!  history conj ["move" 30])
(swap!  history conj ["turn" 50])
; [[move 20] [move 30] [turn 50]]

(first @history)
; ["move" 20]
```

**EDIT:**

```
(println history)
; atom[[["move" 20] ["turn" 90] ["turn" 120]]]

; but an atom's value should be accessed using the @ mark
(println @history)
; [["move" 20] ["turn" 90] ["turn" 120]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to flatten it. You have a vector containing the vector you want as its first and only element. Just use first:

```
user> (first [[["move" 20] ["turn" 90] ["turn" 120]]])
[["move" 20] ["turn" 90] ["turn" 120]]
```

The question is why did you get that nested vector in the first place. Can you share a short snippet of code that generates the vector with the extra nesting?

Comment: Hi Diego, Right now my history evaluates to atom[[["move" 20] ["turn" 90] ["turn" 120]]]. if i do (first history) it throws the error "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Atom"

Comment: @truffle you have to deref an atom, i.e. `(first @history)`.